# Applet throws java.io.FileNotFoundException: http :// localhost:7001/test/lib/log4j.jar

Tags: java, jar, applet, war

I have an applet embedded in JSF page that runs and functions just fine, which also makes a call to SOAP web service. However, it is spitting out a lots of errors on upload that don't really make any difference on how applet works, but delays upload of it. I tried specifying codebase, packaging those jars in various locations of war, and many other options, but nothing really stops these messages. Jars can be found easily under `http://localhost:7001/test`, but not where for some reason it is looking under `http://localhost:7001/test/lib` folder.

Here is what applet looks like in the page:

```
<applet id="applet" 
        name="applet"
        width="496"
        height="122">
   <param name="code" value="applet.Applet"/>
   <param name="archive" value="Applet.jar,Core.jar,log4j.jar,j2ee.jar,jdom-1.1.3.jar"/>
</applet>
```

Lines of the code that throws that error is when Web Service is called:

Error `at ws.FileImporter.<init>(FileImporter.java:42)` - automatically generated code from WSDL:

```
public FileImporter() {
   super(__getWsdlLocation(), FILEIMPORTER_QNAME);
}
```

Error `at applet.util.WSUtil.<init>(WSUtil.java:20)`:

```
private ws.FileImporter service = new ws.FileImporter()
```

Error `at applet.Applet.<init>(Applet.java:76)`:

```
private WSUtil wsUtil = new WSUtil();
```

Here is the error trace:

```
network: Cache entry not found [url:   http://localhost:7001/test/lib/log4j.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:7001/test/lib/log4j.jar with proxy=DIRECT
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http :// localhost:7001/test/lib/log4j.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$1.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.createDefaultCatalogResolver(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createCatalogResolver(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ws.FileImporter.<init>(FileImporter.java:42)
at applet.util.WSUtil.<init>(WSUtil.java:20)
at applet.Applet.<init>(Applet.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:7001/test/lib/log4j.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:7001/test/lib/log4j.jar with proxy=DIRECT

Comment: An applet that depends on j2ee.jar? This is Wrong.

Comment: *"However, it is spitting out a lots of errors on upload that don't really make any difference on how applet works, but delays upload of it."*  1) By 'upload' DYM 'download'?  2) If it has no effect on the workings of the applet, remove the references from the code! 3) And the comment of @BalusC seems highly relevant to whether that Jar should ever have been included in the workings of an applet..  (No.)

Comment: Sorry javaee.jar was a left over from my debugging attempt. In general, all required jars loads fine in the beginning, but then it starts spitting out errors on many other jars that are used by applet, but also many others that no where even used in the project. Javaee.jar is used in core project that applet depends on.

Comment: `network: Cache entry found [url: http://localhost:7001/test/Core.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://localhost:7001/test/Core.jar
cache: Resource http://localhost:7001/test/Core.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://localhost:7001/test/Core.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: ResponseCode for http://localhost:7001/test/Core.jar : 200`